# String slicing with delimiter changing in length

Tags: python

Probably an easy one, but I didn't find a solution by now. My text file that I import into python has a space delimited structure such as

```
20.06.2009 05:00:00        2.6
20.06.2009 06:00:00       21.5
```

I want to split this into a time and a value variable. Slicing the time component is straightforward

```
time = ""
value = ""
for i in lines:
    time += i[0:20]
```

But I can't find a solution for the value component as it contains mostly 3 digits, but sometimes 4, so the number of space delimiters change between time and value (that's why the `re` package doesn't work here). Any solutions?

Comment: Do you really want to store your `value` as a string??

Comment: Just to note that you *could* use regex for this `'([\d]+\.\d)$'` will find `xxx.y` at the end of a line, where there are one or more `x`es. Probably overkill for this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rsplit(' ', 1)` on your string to split based on the last occurrence of a whitespace in your string:

So you could do:

```
x = '20.06.2009 05:00:00        2.6'
y = '20.06.2009 06:00:00       21.5'
items = [x, y]

value = 0
for item in items:
    value += float(item.rsplit(' ', 1)[1])

print(value)
```

**Output**

```
24.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the strip function which removes all spaces:

```
number += float(i[21:].strip())
```

This works also if you have spaces at the end of line.

There is also the `.split()` functions which splits
a line at every space like character or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to `.split()` the entire line with `list1 = x.split(' ')`. What you get at the end is a list.

```
list1 = ['20.06.2009', '05:00:00', '        2.6']
```

So, you can look for spaces on the 3rd element and get rid of em with `.replace()`